# Am I using SOAP if I have a web service?

Tags: web-services, soap

Say I create a simple web service that adds two numbers together.  I send the service two numbers, I get back an answer.  If you like better, I send an account, I get back personal information.

Either way, am I using soap and not knowing it?  I thought I was calling my web service with an http url and my service is returning xml or json.  Where is soap in this?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you create the service? It matters a bit. What tools did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be SOAP - or it could be REST.

What technologies are you using on the server and the client??

Indicators for SOAP:

- Did you define your service using a WSDL (Web Service Description Language) ?
- Does your service have methods that are verb-noun style, e.g. `AddNumber` or `GetInfo` ?

Indicators for REST:

- you don't have a WSDL
- you don't have service methods - you just use a resource identifier (URI) to get your information and you use the standard HTTP verbs like GET, POST, PUT etc. for "doing things"

As for the "where is SOAP in this" - read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), check out the [What Is SOAP?](http://www.soapuser.com/basics1.html) page, or research other places to get a feel for what SOAP is and does... in a nutshell: SOAP takes your input parameter, translates everything into a (XML) message and send that to the server for processing - and does the same thing with the response (XML) message coming back from the server.

Comment: I would suggest that the second SOAP indicator is more of an indication of a *well-written* SOAP web service, but not necessarily SOAP itself.

Comment: WSDL is not an indicator of SOAP, as well as the verb-noun styling isn't. WSDL can be used to define RESTful services as well. The OP is quite confusing... "I built something, let's run and see what I built"...

Comment: @khachik: WSDL for REST?? Never came across one of those.... also: yes, the verb-noun is not **required** for SOAP - but again: I don't know of any REST web service that has that kind of pattern - while lots of SOAP ones do - it's a clue - not a "must have" feature